Staining White Pine (Forgive Me)
I have to trim out several banks of windows with white pine frames stained with (I think) tung oil or Rubio or something. I always avoid staining white pine with ~transparent stuff because of the greasy-looking blotches that pop up (like the right side of this, but here I need to make the banks look like one beautiful integrated wooden thing:

I wish I could get out of this, but I can’t. I see 3 possible approaches:
Try a sanding sealer, wood conditioner, pre-color, etc… been there, done that. Nothing really hides the blotches except solid stain or paint. I think Rubio could be a good match here, so pigment will help, but yeah, a 5” W board with that ugly leopard pattern is gonna be… ugly.
Find a different species that has a matching grain pattern to pine, but stains better… I don’t think this exists. I’ve stained many wood species. Happy to be proved wrong.
Take advantage of the fact that white pine is cheap and buy a lot of it, stain it on the bench, and only use the pieces that come out nice. Sucks, but would work (eventually).
So, here’s my question: anyone know a way to guess (to even 50% accuracy) whether a given white pine board will come out blotchy? All I’ve noticed is that pieces with little black flecks (small mineral streaks I guess, like this seem to come out better. Small sample size though. I’m reaching here, obviously.



So, here’s my question: anyone know a way to guess (to even 50% accuracy) whether a given white pine board will come out blotchy?

This is probably obvious but that's an absolute no. And this is true across the board, for all woods that are prone to blotching and also some that aren't.
If you think about it if this were knowable1, the secret would inevitably get out and then of course everyone would know, because Internet.

Find a different species that has a matching grain pattern to pine, but stains better… I don’t think this exists.

Yup. All the lookalike species to pine are other softwoods, and the rule of thumb is that all softwoods stain poorly in the conventional manner, including, but not limited to, being prone to blotching.

Take advantage of the fact that white pine is cheap and buy a lot of it, stain it on the bench, and only use the pieces that come out nice. Sucks, but would work (eventually).

That is definitely a viable route.
And it's not like the discard pile from this approach would be waste, you just keep it to use it up in other projects.
The actual solution
Don't stain conventionally. Use "gel stain" instead.
Staining pine is debatably the reason it was created, and although its use should not be confined to pine by any means as Bob Flexner has said, "Gel stains ought to be called “pine stain” because they are so effective at eliminating blotching in pine."


I'll cover a couple more of the things in the body text since we're here, for the benefit of future readers if not yours.

Try a sanding sealer, wood conditioner, pre-color, etc… ... Nothing really hides the blotches except solid stain or paint.

Just to clarify, pre-sealing the wood the old way2, using "wood conditioners" and other commercial products intended for this purpose, don't hide blotching but instead lessen, minimise or prevent it.
Any such pre-treatment works by partially sealing off the thirsty parts of the wood that over-absorb finish/stain and go too dark, which is what blotching is.

All I’ve noticed is that pieces with little black flecks (small mineral streaks I guess, like this: https://imgur.com/a/unstained-pine-otKCMRI) seem to come out better.

FWIW I'm pretty sure that isn't pine! Softwoods have no pores and those black flecks look just like how pores present themselves on long-grain surfaces (specifically in this case, on a ring-porous species).
To confirm either way, prep the end grain by shooting with a plane or paring with an ultra-sharp chisel, or sanding very smooth (past 400 grit) and check it for pores. If you see any pores, of any size, then this is hardwood and not softwood.

1 I have no doubt however that there is someone who claims they can do this, but like the numerous claims of infallibility in telling white oak from red oak you can dismiss every one of them outright.
2 For example with dilute shellac or lacquer, called a washcoat or spitcoat, or with diluted glue, a process called sizing.

Thanks so much for the extensive response, Graphus! Really appreciated, learned a lot. I've never used a gel stain - is there a particular top-quality brand you'd recommend? One that would allow me to mimic the semi-transparent look of the photo (tinted linseed, or Rubio, Osmo, tung, something along those lines).
That said, the 2nd photo is definitely white pine, from a load from a local cabinet shop that I keep on hand for lower-budget projects. It's admittedly an unusual one! I'll try the end-grain trick just because it's new to me. Maybe some alder or something snuck in there.

My main finish recommendation would be a blanket not Minwax but beyond that I often don't recommend anything specific. I feel you really have to do your due diligence here because of the exact result you're after — no amount of online recommendations can really help one nail an exact result because of the vagaries of photography, coupled then with monitor/phone screen differences.

This is, incidentally, why wood identification cannot be done reliably online, or through pictures in general. There are some woods that are naturally clearly identifiable, particularly if you can also view the end grain in the case of hardwoods, but the opposite it also not rare. And in the softwood world, with the easy substitution of subspecies or different species entirely under the blanket name "pine" it confuses the picture of what is most definitely pine and what is a stand-in or proxy (and it varies by region — hemlock in some parts, spruce in another, fir in a third and so on).
